# Merging strings together with separator berween them in C#

Tags: c#

I needed to merge strings that are inside `List<string>` together into oneliner. I came up with simple solution but I am not sure if it's the best way to go.

First version with problematic `,` on string start:

```
string benchmarkiUjemneDatyRazem = "";
foreach (string s in benchmarkiUjemne) {
    benchmarkiUjemneDatyRazem = benchmarkiUjemneDatyRazem + "," + s;
}
```

Second version (Linq power) but still with ` :

```
string benchmarkiUjemneDatyRazem = benchmarkiUjemne.Aggregate("", (current, s) => current + "," + s);
```

Working version without `,` but amount of lines makes some pain in later reading it:

```
   int b = 0;
   string benchmarkiUjemneDatyRazem = "";
   foreach (string s in benchmarkiUjemne) {
       if (b == 0) {
          b = 1;
          benchmarkiUjemneDatyRazem = s;
          continue;
       }
       benchmarkiUjemneDatyRazem = benchmarkiUjemneDatyRazem + "," + s;
  }
```

Final version that I came up with was based on Linq with Subsitute to first char:

```
    string benchmarkiUjemneDatyRazem = benchmarkiUjemne.Aggregate("", (current, s) => current + "," + s).Substring(1);
```

Is this good approach to this problem ? Or there's better way to actually do it? Like using StringBuilder or so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using .Net 4, you can use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx) (in earlier versions this will work only if `benchmarkiUjemne` is a `string[]`):

```
string result = string.Join(",", benchmarkiUjemne);
```

If this is .Net 3.5 or older, you can still use it by calling `ToArray` on the list:

```
string result = string.Join(",", benchmarkiUjemne.ToArray());
```

Comment: Which you can easily solve by calling .ToArray() on the List<string>. =)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx):

```
var res = string.Join(",", benchmarkiUjemne);
```